# How do you set the column width on a QTreeView?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreeview

Bear with me, I'm still new to QT and am having trouble wrapping my brain around how it does things.

I've created and populated a QTreeView with two columns:

```
class AppForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(AppForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.view = QTreeView()
        self.view.setColumnWidth(0, 800)
        self.view.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
```

Everything's working great, except the columns are extremely narrow. I hoped that setColumnWidth(0, 800) would widen the first column, but it doesn't seem to be having any effect. What's the proper method for setting column widths?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you call `setColumnWidth`, Qt will do the equivalent of:

```
self.view.header().resizeSection(column, width)
```

Then, when you call `setModel`, Qt will (amongst other things) do the equivalent of:

```
self.view.header().setModel(model)
```

So the column width *does* get set - just not on the model the tree view ends up with.

`tl;dr`: set the column width *after* you set the model.

**EDIT**

Here's a simple demo script based on your example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.view = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.view.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)
        parent = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
        for item in 'One Two Three Four'.split():
            parent.appendRow([
                QtGui.QStandardItem(item),
                QtGui.QStandardItem(),
                QtGui.QStandardItem(),
                ])
        self.view.setColumnWidth(0, 800)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I moved setColumnWidth below setModel, but it still doesn't seem to be having an effect. Is the problem that I haven't populated it or set the amount of columns yet?

Comment: @ashground. I've added a demo script to my answer that works for me.

Comment: Awesome -- I moved setColumnWidth into a different function so that it's called after it populates the tree. Everything's working as expected now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12):

```
self.view.resizeColumnToContents(0)
```

[This](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#resizeColumnToContents) makes sure that given column's width and height are set to match with content.

Comment: QTreeView' object has no attribute 'resizeColumnsToContents'

Comment: resizeColumnToContents(), not Columns